# Efficient, large-scale competition scoring in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, numba

Consider a large dataframe of scores `S` containing entries like the following. Each row represents a contest between a subset of the participants `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`.

```
 A     B    C   D
0.1  0.3  0.8    1
  1  0.2  NaN  NaN
0.7  NaN    2  0.5
NaN   4   0.6  0.8
```

The way to read the matrix above is: looking at the first row, the participant `A` scored `0.1` in that round, `B` scored `0.3`, and so forth.

I need to build a triangular matrix `C` where `C[X,Y]` stores how much better participant `X` was than participant `Y`. More specifically, `C[X,Y]` would hold the **mean** % difference in score between `X` and `Y`.

From the example above:

```
C[A,B] = 100 * ((0.1 - 0.3)/0.3 + (1 - 0.2)/0.2) = 33%
```

My matrix `S` is huge, so I am hoping to take advantage of JIT (Numba?) or built-in methods in `numpy` or `pandas`. I certainly want to avoid having a nested loop, since  `S` has millions of rows.

Does an efficient algorithm for the above have a name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at a NumPy based solution and thus let's assume that the input data is in an array named `a`. Now, the number of pairwise combinations for 4 such variables would be `4*3/2 = 6`. We can generate the IDs corresponding to such combinations with [`np.triu_indices()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html#numpy.triu_indices). Then, we index into the columns of `a` with those indices. We perform the subtractions and divisions and simply add the columns ignoring the NaN affected results with [`np.nansum()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html) for the desired output.

Thus, we would have an implementation like so -

```
R,C = np.triu_indices(a.shape[1],1)
out = 100*np.nansum((a[:,R] - a[:,C])/a[:,C],0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [121]: a
Out[121]: 
array([[ 0.1,  0.3,  0.8,  1. ],
       [ 1. ,  0.2,  nan,  nan],
       [ 0.7,  nan,  2. ,  0.5],
       [ nan,  4. ,  0.6,  0.8]])

In [122]: out
Out[122]: 
array([ 333.33333333, -152.5       ,  -50.        ,  504.16666667,
        330.        ,  255.        ])

In [123]: 100 * ((0.1 - 0.3)/0.3 + (1 - 0.2)/0.2) # Sample's first o/p elem
Out[123]: 333.33333333333337
```

If you need the output as `(4,4)` array, we can use [`Scipy's squareform`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html) -

```
In [124]: from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

In [125]: out2D = squareform(out)
```

Let's convert to a pandas dataframe for a good visual feedback -

```
In [126]: pd.DataFrame(out2D,index=list('ABCD'),columns=list('ABCD'))
Out[126]: 
            A           B           C    D
A    0.000000  333.333333 -152.500000  -50
B  333.333333    0.000000  504.166667  330
C -152.500000  504.166667    0.000000  255
D  -50.000000  330.000000  255.000000    0
```

Let's compute `[B,C]` manually and check back -

```
In [127]: 100 * ((0.3 - 0.8)/0.8 + (4 - 0.6)/0.6)
Out[127]: 504.1666666666667
```